# How to use the if-else correctly so I get either a number or the text "not a number"?

Tags: python, if-statement

This is a high school assignment, the teacher gave us a code block using try-except and then told us to change it to an if-else command. I keep on encountering an error and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Code from teacher:

```
data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]
for x in data:
  try:
    print(x/2)
  except:
    print("Not a number")
```

This is the if-else code I tried but kept on getting an error:

```
data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]
for x in data:
  if x:
    print(x/2)
  else:
    print("Not a number")
```

Error on line 4:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

I'm expecting the outcome of:

```
5
4.5
Not a number
2
Not a number
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working for you is because you are looping through an array where some values are integers and others such as "Cindi" are not. There is no possible way to do "Cindi"/2 as this would throw an exception.

You may want to use isinstance(x, int) instead which checks whether the value in your array is a number. If that evaluates to true, then it is a number, else it is not a number

Answer (score 0):

I think the most suitable way to do this using the isistance(x,int) since you can't divide a string

data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]

for x in data:

```
if isinstance(x, (int)):
    print(x/2)
else:
    print("Not a number")
```

Comment: If I change the first value from `10` to `10.0` I'm told that it is not a number. That is not really true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that caters for all number types **including integers and decimals**, then you can modify the condition to first check for String types

```
data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]
for x in data:
  if isinstance(x, (str)):
    print("Not a number")
  else:
    print(x/2)
```

**NOTE:** If there are values with any other data types such as Boolean or collection types, then this solution would not be the optimal one

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]
for x in data:
 try:
   print(x/2)
 except:
   print("Not a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason it works with try and except is because this methods check if the operation could be done like if

number /2 is possible it would try to do that

then again it would try to do 'cindi'/2 but this cant be done as its against law of nature

so it would go on except on such cases

where as for this

```
data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]
for x in data:
  if isinstance(x,(int,float)):
    print(x/2)
  else:
    print("Not a number")
```

you would have to check explicity using isinstance() function for a number
if its not a number then it would go to else part
if each x in data is an instance of either int or float (i.e., a number)

Answer (score 0):

Use `type` to check for the type of the item in the list and skip the string ones

```
data = [10, 9, "Cindi", 4, "8"]
for x in data:
    if type(x) is not str:
        print (x)
```